# How to use the awaitMessages function in discord.js

Tags: discord.js, dm

I have some code for discord.js that sends a user a DM when they join the server. They then have to enter the password given to them, and it will then give them a role that allows them access to channels.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    console.log("Joined");
    guildMember.send("Welcome to the server! Please enter the password given to you to gain access to the server:")
      .then(function(){
        guildMember.awaitMessages(response => message.content, {
          max: 1,
          time: 300000000,
          errors: ['time'],
        })
        .then((collected) => {
            if(response.content === "Pass"){
              guildMember.send("Correct password! You now have access to the server.");
            }
            else{
              guildMember.send("Incorrect password! Please try again.");
            }
          })
          .catch(function(){
            guildMember.send('You didnt input the password in time.');
          });
      });
});

client.login("token");
```

The thing is, I don't really know how to use the `awaitResponses` function. I do not know how to call it, because all the tutorials I find use it with `message.member`.

When I run my code, I get these three errors:
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: guildMember.awaitMessages is not a function`

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)

`Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.`

I do not know what lines these are referring to, so I am very confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick rundown on how awaitMessages works:

First of all, the `.awaitMessages()` function extends [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel), meaning you had already messed up a little bit by extending the `GuildMember` object instead. - You could easily fetch a channel using

```
const channelObject = guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID Here'); // Gets a channel object based on it's ID
const channelObject = guildMember.guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.name === 'channel name here') // Gets a channel object based on it's name
```

`awaitMessages()` also gives you the ability to add a filter for a certain condition an input must have.
Let's take the freshly new member as an example. We could simply tell the client to only accept input from members who have the same id as the guildMember object, so basically only the new Member.

```
const filter = m => m.author.id === guildMember.id
```

Now, finally, after we've gathered all of the resources needed, this should be our final code to await Messages.

```
const channelObject = guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('Channel ID Here');
    const filter = m => m.author.id === guildMember.id
    channelObject.awaitMessages(filter, {
        max: 1, // Requires only one message input
        time: 300000000, // Maximum amount of time the bot will await messages for
        errors: 'time' // would give us the error incase time runs out.
    })
```

To read more about `awaitMessages()`, [click here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)!

Comment: Thank you for all your help! I just have one more question: I see you're doing this by using `awaitMessages` with the `channelObject`, but I would like to do it in DMs. How would I do this?

Comment: DMs are considered as Channels!
If you'd like to `awaitMessages` once a user messages a client, you could simply use the `message.channel` function, which would give you the Channel Object of the DMs between the user and the bot :)